# WebAuthenticationBrowser.AuthenticateAsync() kills the UWP app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have a universal Windows 10 app where I use

```
var token = await WebAuthenticationBrowser.AuthenticateAsync(...)
```

to authenticate user against facebook. It all works fine in a common scenario when it's just the foreground app. However when I add a BackgroundMediaPlayer, start music playback and communication between foreground and background, calling

```
var token = await WebAuthenticationBrowser.AuthenticateAsync(...)
```

actually kills my foreground app. When user finishes the authentication in the broker, he is taken back to the app - but it was killed and is re-instantiated. This of course means that awaiting AuthenticateAsync() doesn't produce any results, because it's a new instance of the app.

I would understand this behavior when calling `WebAuthenticationBrowser.AuthenticateAndContinue()` which was introduced in WP8.1, but this API has been deprecated in UWP.

So my questions are - is this expected behavior (app being killed and relaunched)? If so, how do I get the token from WebAuthenticationBroker during app relaunch?

Here is a sample project to reproduce (with exact steps in a txt file): https://t.co/XtmESd9o5r
Here is a video running the sample (first launch the broker without BackgroundMediaPlayer running, then with it running): http://youtu.be/VcZXBOTiD1Y

I started a conversation about this in twitter: https://twitter.com/lancewmccarthy/status/685152844849262593 but so far the only help I got was to "check the activation kind" with this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind.aspx.

The link describes activationKind has "WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation", but 
1) that's only for Windows Phone, not Windows 10
2) when you run the sample, you will never receive it. Only "Launched", with previousExecutionState "Terminated"

Comment: Maybe you should try to find out why the app terminates when a background task is running in the first place. I don't think this should be normal behavior.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to find out. The system suspends the app when calling the broker, after which it may or may not kill the app completely. But at this point there is nothing the app can do to find out the reason, since it's suspended.

Comment: I tried out your code, it's not necessarily the second time navigate to the the app that restarts the foreground process, sometimes I have to try several times to reproduce. Looks like an intermittent terminate.